# my menu button does not line up

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.spencedesign.netau.net/singaporehomemenu.html
 This is the link to my page. When you click on menu it closes, or opens the menu, by bringing you to the other page, that doesn't have the menu. But, on the other page the menu button is not lined up. Even though the code for the button is the same on each page. Could someone tell me what I can do to fix this. Also, I don't know any javascript, so I had to make two pages instead of making the menu button work as an actual button and bring up/close the menu on one page. If anyone knows javascript, and knows a simple way to make the above scenario possible that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: this http://www.spencedesign.netau.net/singaporebackground.jpg image is too big

Comment: Don't think its a good idea to use 2 pages for a simple functionality. Also I'd suggest you read up on basic javascript if you're making your own site, can be very helpful. You can start at w3schools.com.

Comment: @Fahad did i see w3schols.com .....

Comment: @NullPointer yes I did mention it. Anything wrong? :S

Comment: @Fahad yes ... we does not recommended w3schools since it have many bug ... you can see w3fools.com

Comment: @NullPointer hmm I'll go through it. Thanks :)

Comment: Hahah w3fools is funny, I have recently realized the faults in w3schools. But in all seriousness, does anyone have a suggestion to learn javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using javascript.
Add this to your  < head > tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMenu() {
        if (menu.style.display != "none") {
            menu.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            menu.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And write this in your < body > section:

```
<div id="menuButton" onclick="showMenu()">Menu
</div>
```

This ought to do the trick. :)